# PHP Curl adds '\' to apostrophe character sending to PHP but ASP based server

Tags: php, curl

I have a 3rd party ASP based server which has a PHP page which takes in form data. From my web page I have a PHP script which sends fields to the PHP page using curl. Everything works fine except if a user includes an apostrophe character to the text! In the back end it is received as "\'".

What is even odder is that it only does this from my hosted website. When I test locally it works fine.

i don't have a control on my hosted site. All i have to work on my php curl function.

it works perfect on my localhost.

here is the sample code

> ```
>   $this->headers[] = 'Accept: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
>     $this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
>     $this->headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
> ```

```
    $post_var = 'post='.urlencode(stripslashes("it's Me Ali"));

    $this->ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,      $this->headers);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,          FALSE);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,       $this->USER_AGENT);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $this->cookie);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $this->cookie);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,          $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/');
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,        "gzip");
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  TRUE);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  TRUE);

    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL,         'http://www.example.com/form.php');
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST,        TRUE);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $post_var);

    $get_page = curl_exec($this->ch);
    echo $get_page;
    curl_close($this->ch);
```

Comment: Fix the problem in `http://www.myhostsite.com/form.php` not in the curl call.

Comment: i donot have access to http://www.myhostsite.com/form.php its service that i have to use without any privilege

Comment: If you do not have access, you cannot fix *their* magic_quotes problem. Question answered. Problem not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Magic_quotes is turned on, and this is not necessarily a good thing since it is now considered deprecated.

You can only turn this on in the ini file. If you cant, the use strip_slashes to remove them.

You can loop through your get and post vars to remove the slashes at the top of the page.