# CURL and magic_quotes

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with cURL and magic_quotes.

for different reasons i cannot turn magic_quotes off.
But i do need to disable this feature when I create a CURL POST request.

In this CURL POST request I pass a variable that contains XML and xml opening tag, something like this:

```
$xml_request = ' <?xml version="1.0"?><SaleRequest> <CustomerData> <Email>alex@virtuman.com</Email> <CustomerData> <SaleRequest>';
```

after I create a curl post request:

```
$url="https://my.secureserver.com/parsexmlscript.cgi";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xml=".$xml_request);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

in the result: request received on the secure server - first opening tag looks like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
```

(with version attribute is with magic quotes)
after this xml parser dies telling me that XML document is not well formed.

is there any way to disable magic quotes for only one script that creates this post request ?

or may be there is any other way of getting around it ?

any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can't you just `stripslashes($xml_request)` before passing it to curl?

Comment: well i already tried that.. doesnot really work. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: [Also, do you really have that problem since 2003?](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10224870)

Comment: No but i have exactly the same problem. i am not a native English so cant really explain well.

Comment: And why don't you post the code that *you* have a problem with? Also please show exactly what alternative code you already tried.

Comment: here is my problem. i think i was not able to explain well thats why i asked this question. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574376/php-curl-adds-to-apostrophe-character-sending-to-php-but-asp-based-server

Comment: Well. Posting an entirely unrelated question doesn't help you with your original problem. Which is also not understandable, since you didn't post the relavant and complete code. Go back and edit your question. And I want to see where exactly you purportedly applied stripslashes.

Comment: i have updated the code. please check.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `base64_encode( $xmldata )` and in perl `base64_decode( $incomingdata )` ?

This way php has no strange characters to encode.

Another way is to replace all quotes with 2 tildes like `str_replace("'", "~~", $outgoingstring);` and on the incoming script you replace them back.

Answer (score 0):

Possible steps:

- try `stripslashes($xml_request)` in your actual code
- in 2003 `set_magic_quotes_runtime(0)` might have helped
- .htaccess `php_flag magic_quotes off` maybe wrapped in a `<Files specific.php>`

Most of that information is in the PHP manual about [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/magic_quotes)

Comments will not be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xml_request = str_replace("\\", "", $result);
```